# Combine link_to and simple_format in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

in Rails I have to create an hyperlink using link_to.

I would like to introduce \n in the text of this hyperlink and to make it working I have to use the function simple_format. How can I concatenate the two? I tried only in the text but it doesn't work. If I put it around the whole link_to, I got an error.

Comment: Add code please as to what is not working this will make it easier for us to explain how to get that working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a block of code to the `link_to` method like:

```
link_to(options = {}, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

Inside the block of code you can add the logic you need for the text of the link.

PD: please add your current code to the question